# Getting code to ask a different set of questions under one variable

Tags: python

I'm making a program which is a phone trouble-shooter which identifies keywords and then reads and prints off a document which has solutions on it depending on said keyword. Now with my code i ask what the problem is and if i say liquid i want the liquid document to print and a string of questions related to liquid problems to be presented. Now when i do this it keeps asking the first set of questions which is power. Can anyone help me so it goes to the right string of questions?

```
#Task 2 Trouble-Shooter 1.0
#Zacharriah River Howells
import time
print('Hello and welcome to the mobile phone Trouble-Shooter!')
time.sleep(2)
problem = input('Please input what is wrong with your phone')
if "power" in problem:
    f = open('Power.txt', 'r')
    solution1 = f.readlines()
    print(solution1[0])
    f.close()
if "battery" in problem:
    f = open('Power.txt', 'r')
    solution1 = f.readlines()
    print(solution1[0])
    f.close()
time.sleep(2)

print('Have you charged your phone overnight? if not do so')
time.sleep(1)
powerans = input('Does your phone turn on now?')
if powerans == 'yes':
    f = open('Power.txt', 'r')
    solution1 = f.readlines()
    print(solution1[1])
    f.close()
    exit()

elif powerans == 'no':
    f = open('Power.txt', 'r')
    solution2 = f.readlines()
    print(solution2[2])
    f.close()
    exit()

if "liquid" in problem:
    f = open('Liquid.txt', 'r')
    solution1 = f.readlines()
    print(solution1[0])
    f.close()
if "water" in problem:
    f = open('Liquid.txt', 'r')
    solution1 = f.readlines()
    print(solution1[0])
    f.close()
time.sleep(2)

print('Have you let your phone dry in a container filled with rice?')
time.sleep(1)
liquidans = input('Does your phone turn on now?')
if liquidans == 'yes':
    f = open('Liquid.txt', 'r')
    solution1 = f.readlines()
    print(solution3[1])
    f.close()
    exit()

elif liquidans == 'no':
    f = open('Liquid.txt', 'r')
    solution2 = f.readlines()
    print(solution4[2])
    f.close()
    exit()

if "software" in problem:
    f = open('Software.txt', 'r')
    solution1 = f.readlines()
    print(solution1[0])
    f.close()
if "apps" in problem:
    f = open('Software.txt', 'r')
    solution1 = f.readlines()
    print(solution1[0])
    f.close()
time.sleep(2)

print('Have you tried reinstalling the app?')
time.sleep(1)
softeareans = input('Does your phone turn on now?')
if softwareans == 'yes':
    f = open('Software.txt', 'r')
    solution1 = f.readlines()
    print(solution5[1])
    f.close()
    exit()

elif softwareans == 'no':
    f = open('Software.txt', 'r')
    solution2 = f.readlines()
    print(solution6[2])
    f.close()
    exit()

if "hardware" in problem:
    f = open('Hardware.txt', 'r')
    solution1 = f.readlines()
    print(solution1[0])
    f.close()
if "display" in problem:
    f = open('Hardware.txt', 'r')
    solution1 = f.readlines()
    print(solution1[0])
    f.close()
time.sleep(2)

print('Have you tried installing the newest system update?')
time.sleep(1)
hardwareans = input('Does your phone turn on now?')
if hardewareans == 'yes':
    f = open('Hardware.txt', 'r')
    solution1 = f.readlines()
    print(solution7[1])
    f.close()
    exit()

elif hardwareans == 'no':
    f = open('Hardware.txt', 'r')
    solution2 = f.readlines()
    print(solution8[2])
    f.close()
    exit()

if "unable" in problem:
    f = open('Unidentifiable.txt', 'r')
    solution1 = f.readlines()
    print(solution1[0])
    f.close()
if "dunno" in problem:
    f = open('Unidentifiable.txt', 'r')
    solution1 = f.readlines()
    print(solution1[0])
    f.close()
time.sleep(2)
print('We cannot identify uour problem you can either')
time.sleep(1)
print('Visit our store')
time.sleep(1)
print('Visit our website')

loop = input('Would you like to return to the start of the trouble-shooter?')
if loop == 'yes':
    problem()
else:
     exit()
```

Comment: Tell us what is _not_ working.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions are all at first level indentation, so they'll all be asked no matter what the user answers. If, as your question states, certain questions should be asked only when the user replies with "liquid", then these questions should be within the [if] statement to "liquid". For example:

```
if "power" in problem:
    f = open('Power.txt', 'r')
    solution1 = f.readlines()
    print(solution1[0])
    f.close()
    print('Have you charged your phone overnight? if not do so')
    time.sleep(1)
    powerans = input('Does your phone turn on now?')
```

Or better yet, have questions in defined functions, and call these functions when they apply.

Edit: please note, if questions have dependencies between them, you might be better off building a tree-like data structure with the different answer options and linking to the files and answers that apply for either answer.